# Browser-based upload - AWS S3 Signed POST - Verify correct file is uploaded

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to understand how can I inform the backend that the user has uploaded a file to s3, its key and preventing the user from tampering with the key.

The files to be uploaded are private, meaning I'm generating signed GET URLs to download the files when the user wants them. 
I'm using boto3 to create the presigned POST urls, so I'm not using a home-made implementation, but this is library-agnostic.

I have a javascript frontend and a backend API, the userflow for uploading a file would be more or less:

- Browser -> API (GET /sign):

  - Request:

    - > ```
      > {
      >   filename: 'something.txt
      >   size: 12345
      >   type: image/jpeg
      > }
      > ```
  - Response:

    - The backend using filename calculates **a random key** (so that collision is avoided), then using ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, BUCKET_NAME and some more info calculates a signature, sending back the required parameters to the frontend
    - Backend does not save any data in its db, as there's no actual data until the client uploads the file.
    - > ```
      > {
      >     url: https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com
      >     fields: {
      >         acl: 'private',
      >         key: 'mykey', 
      >         signature: 'mysignature', 
      >         policy: 'mybase64 encoded policy'
      >     }
      > }
      > ```
- Browser -> s3 (POST mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com):

  - Request:

    - Browser sends the actual file and the signed parameters as a multipart/form-data
    - > ```
      > {
      >         acl: 'private',
      >         key: 'mykey', 
      >         signature: 'mysignature', 
      >         policy: 'mybase64 encoded policy'
      > }
      > ```
  - Response (documentation aws RESTObjectPOST):

    - Among headers and body we have:

      - Bucket
      - Key
      - ETag (which "is an MD5 hash of the object")
      - Location

Many javascript libraries and guides (i.e. [FineUploader](https://github.com/FineUploader/php-s3-server/blob/master/endpoint.php#L241), [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails#callbacks-done)) now simply proxies the key from the POST response to the backend. Then the backend checks that the file exists and adds the new file key to its database.

Now, the files to be uploaded are private, meaning I'm generating signed GET URLs to download the files when the user wants them.
Let's say there's **UserA** and **UserB**, **UserB** uploaded **FileB**.
What's preventing UserA from uploading a file, but sending to the backend the FileB key (which can be guessed or just be random input until they get something existing) and thus the backend saving that userA has fileB?

What I tought of:

- keys are random and a key/file can only belong to one user, thus when userA tells "I've uploaded fileB" the backend responds "fileB is of another user"/"Error". This seems to me the easiest way to solve the problem, but I think I'm missing something (concurrency, leftover files,...)
- On GET /sign backend stores "UserA will upload FileA", thus on the callback the backend checks that UserA wanted to upload FileA, if mismatching "Error"
- Checking the ETag returned by s3, so that they must have the file to calculate its md5 and the user can't get FileB.
- Setting in the policy that the key is XXXX, and on the callback recalculate the signature and checking that it's the same.
- Using a temporary upload bucket so that a malicious user would need not only to guess a random key but also that this key is of a file being uploaded now. When the callback is called the backend moves the file with the specified key to the final bucket.

Maybe I'm overlooking something, but I can't find any solution online apart from (I think) hacky ones (setting the key to start with the username, ...).

I can't post more than two links, so some aws documentation is left out.

Comment: You are on track with your second suggested approach. You'll have to save the signed URL to user mapping on the server(you could use a key value store like redis) and then after the upload, compare the keys from the client with the one stored on server.